# Unable to ignore lint for stories folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, eslint

I have a react project in following structure.

[image]

I wish to ignore the `stories` folder from lint checks.

Thus added the file `.eslintignore`.

And within there added the following.

```
.DS_Store
.idea
lib
.sass_cache
test-results
.jest-cache
stories/**
storybook-static
```

But when I perform `npm run lint`, the lint still checks for the stories folder. Why?

Also tried `stories` and `stories/*` in the `.eslintignore` file with same result.

The lint script in package.json file.

```
"lint": "npm run lint:lockfile && npm run lint:code && npm run lint:snapshots",
"lint:lockfile": "lockfile-lint --path package-lock.json --allowed-hosts github yarn --validate-https",
"lint:code": "npm run eslint -- --ext js,jsx .",
"lint:snapshots": "npm run eslint -- --ext snap .",
"eslint": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore",
```

Also tried updating the script to following, and same results.

```
"eslint": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore stories",
```

Comment: just `stories` should ignore the entire folder.

Comment: @Joel updated to stories again and performing npm run lint via terminal. Same outcome.